# Why Visual Studio code and most of the applications are not installing in fresh windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation

I am trying to install Visual Studio Code in my fresh windows 10 but it is throwing an error `Setup was unable to create a directory`

```
Error 5: Access is denied
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your UAC(User Account Control) is turned off, and you are running the install as Admin (because you already are admin), it seems like a permission issue and not a UAC issue. Try this:

1. Create a folder name "Temp" under C:\ // This step is important, the
   folder has to exist.
2. Right click the Computer in Start menu and select Properties. Click
3. Advanced System Setting. In System Properties windows, click
   Advanced tab.
4. Click Environment Variables button. Under User
   variables list, double click TMP.
5. Change Variable value: from
   "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp" to "C:\Temp".

Try to install.